# Unbound will restart, but will not reload

Tags: configuration, freebsd, jail, unbound

I am running `unbound` in a FreeBSD 11.3 jail, and have noted some behaviour that seems strange (at least to me!)

When restarting the unbound service, it works error-free:

```
service unbound restart

# Stopping unbound.
# Waiting for PIDS: 80729.
# Obtaining a trust anchor...
# Starting unbound.
```

I have confirmed that it is all running a-ok and as expected.

However, when attempting to reload unbound (without a full restart) via `unbound-control`, it throws some config errors...

```
unbound-control -c /usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf reload

# /usr/local/etc/unbound/mnt/config/unbound.conf:25: error: unknown keyword 'log-replies'
# /usr/local/etc/unbound/mnt/config/unbound.conf:25: error: stray ':'
# /usr/local/etc/unbound/mnt/config/unbound.conf:25: error: unknown keyword 'yes'
# /usr/local/etc/unbound/mnt/config/unbound.conf:27: error: unknown keyword 'log-tag-queryreply'
# /usr/local/etc/unbound/mnt/config/unbound.conf:27: error: stray ':'
# /usr/local/etc/unbound/mnt/config/unbound.conf:27: error: unknown keyword 'yes'
...
...
...
# read /usr/local/etc/unbound/unbound.conf failed: 20 errors in configuration file
# [1594189698] unbound-control[37432:0] fatal error: could not read config file
```

Does anyone know why a restart would work, yet a reload wouldn't?  I have confirmed that the config being referenced is the same in both cases (by deliberately mis-formatting it to see if `service unbound restart` fails)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does `service unbound reload` work? If yes, why don't you use it?

Comment: See answer - thank you!!  (I didn't realise ```reload``` could be invoked via ```service```)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service unbound reload` does work.

It doesn't really 'fix' whatever the underlying bug is - but solves the problem for my use-case.

Credit to @arrowd for the answer

Comment: for some reason it won't let me accept my own answer... probably because I'm quite new to SO...  would be great if an admin could do so :)

Comment: Just wait a day or something like that. Then you'll be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: I think, `service unbound reload` does something more than `unbound-control -c <...>/unbound.conf reload`, that's why it works. If you are interested, you can examine the rc script in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/unbound` to figure out the difference.